# Is sending duplicated keys possible when using PHP soap for DHL express SOAP server

Tags: php, soap

I need to send several ExportedLineItems to DHL EXPRESS soap server, but it seams that they are rejecting the usual method to send duplicated array key.
Looking at the WSD it should be possible
https://wsbexpress.dhl.com/gbl/expressRateBook?WSDL
When I pass following array (abrevation)

```
$client = new SoapClient(URL_ADDR, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 1,  'use' => SOAP_LITERAL));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(Array(new WsseAuthHeader(USERNAME, PASSWORD)));   

//array abrevation ....
'ExportDeclaration' => [
                'InvoiceDate' => date("Y-m-d"),
                'InvoiceNumber' => '123456_invoice',
                'ExportLineItems' => [
                    'ExportLineItem' =>[ 
                        'ItemNumber' => '1',
                        'Quantity' => '1',
                        'QuantityUnitOfMeasurement' => 'KG',
                        'ItemDescription' => 'X15_01',
                        'UnitPrice' => '239',
                        'NetWeight' => '0.25',
                        'GrossWeight' => '0.3', 
                    ]   
                ]
            ],
//...
$result = $client->createShipmentRequest($data);
```

Code above gets correct result. But i need to pass more then one ExportLineItem so i used following array

```
$client = new SoapClient(URL_ADDR, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 1,  'use' => SOAP_LITERAL));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(Array(new WsseAuthHeader(USERNAME, PASSWORD)));   
//... array abrevation
'ExportDeclaration' => [
                    'InvoiceDate' => date("Y-m-d"),
                    'InvoiceNumber' => '123456_invoice',
                    'ExportLineItems' => [
                        'ExportLineItem' =>[ 
                            0 => [
                                'ItemNumber' => '1',
                                'Quantity' => '1',
                                'QuantityUnitOfMeasurement' => 'KG',
                                'ItemDescription' => 'X15_01',
                                'UnitPrice' => '239',
                                'NetWeight' => '0.25',
                                'GrossWeight' => '0.3', 
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'ItemNumber' => '2',
                                'Quantity' => '2',
                                'QuantityUnitOfMeasurement' => 'KG',
                                'ItemDescription' => 'X15_02',
                                'UnitPrice' => '123',
                                'NetWeight' => '0.24',
                                'GrossWeight' => '0.34',    
                            ]
                        ]   
                    ]
                ],
//...
$result = $client->createShipmentRequest($data);
```

This time i receive an error 'Encoding: object has no 'ItemNumber' property'. I realy do not know what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried asking DHL how to handle this? This does not look like a pure programming issue to me

Comment: Hello Nico. Thanks for reading my question. It seams that some ware along the line (weather in wsdl or in  the way i am using PHP soap implementation) lies an error. I have sent pure XML to their API and received good result. Meaning that it is possible. Before I post my solution i hope that someone will come with the real solution of sending array as expected instead of pure xml string as i did. Since that is not a good solution.